# Interestingly restricted compositions of $n$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Let $n$ be a non-negative integer. How many compositions of $n$ are there where the $i$-th part has the same parity as $i$?

The main problem I'm having with this problem is that I can't really formulate a single generating function for the set of all tuples of natural numbers where the $i$-th element has the same parity as $i$. How should I proceed?

Comment: Maybe you could break this into cases by the number of parts, subtract 1 from $n$ for each odd partition, and then just partition into even parts.

Comment: Could you write up an answer on how exactly to do that?

Comment: Since you mention the $i$th part: are you treating, for instance, the sum $1 + 4 + 5$ as distinct from $1 + 5 + 4$? I would try to help, but I am not 100% clear on what you mean by "$i$th part".

Comment: Yes, those two sums are distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be the number of compositions of $n$ whose $i$-the part has the same parity as $i$, and let $b_n$ be the number of compositions of $n$ whose $i$-the part has the opposite parity to $i$. Considering the possible values of the first part of a composition of $n$, we see that

$$a_{2n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^nb_{2k}\quad\text{ and }\quad a_{2n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b_{2k+1}$$

and

$$b_{2n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{2k+1}\quad\text{ and }\quad b_{2n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{2k}\;,$$

and hence that

$$\left\{\begin{align*}a_n&=a_{n-2}+b_{n-1}\\
b_n&=a_{n-2}+b_{n-2}\;.
\end{align*}\right.\tag{1}$$

If we make the blanket assumption that $a_n=b_n=0$ for all $n<0$ and set $a_0=0$ and $b_0=1$, $(1)$ is valid for all $n\in\Bbb Z$ except in the case of $b_0$, adding an [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) term to get

$$\left\{\begin{align*}a_n&=a_{n-2}+b_{n-1}\\
b_n&=a_{n-2}+b_{n-2}+[n=0]\;.
\end{align*}\right.\tag{2}$$

fixes this.

Let

$$A(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n\quad\text{and}\quad B(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}b_nx^n$$

be the generating functions for the two sequences. Then multiplying the recurrences $(2)$ by $x^n$ and summing over $n\ge 0$ yields

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
A(x)&=x^2A(x)+xB(x)\\
B(x)&=x^2A(x)+x^2B(x)+1\;.
\end{align*}\right.$$

Then

$$B(x)=\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}A(x)+\frac1{1-x^2}$$

and

$$A(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2}B(x)=\frac{x^3}{(1-x^2)^2}A(x)+\frac{x}{(1-x^2)^2}\;,$$

so

$$\begin{align*}
A(x)&=\frac{x}{1-x^2}\left(1-\frac{x^3}{(1-x^2)^2}\right)^{-1}\\\\
&=\frac{x}{1-x^2}\cdot\frac{(1-x^2)^2}{1-2x^2-x^3+x^4}\\\\
&=\frac{x(1-x)}{1-2x^2-x^3+x^4}
\end{align*}$$

and

$$\begin{align*}
B(x)&=\frac{1-x^2}xA(x)\\\\
&=\frac{(1-x)^2(1+x)}{1-2x^2-x^3+x^4}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Some actual numbers:

$$\begin{array}{rccc}
n:&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13\\
a_n:&0&1&0&2&1&3&4&5&10&11&21&27&43&64\\
b_n:&1&0&1&1&1&3&2&6&6&11&16&22&37&43
\end{array}$$

OEIS has $\langle a_n+b_n:n\ge 0\rangle=\langle b_{n+2}:n\ge 0\rangle$ as [OEIS A062200](http://oeis.org/A062200) and $\langle a_n:n\ge 0\rangle$ as [OEIS A122514](http://oeis.org/A122514). It has little more information beyond the recurrence

$$b_n=2b_{n-2}+b_{n-3}-b_{n-4}\;,$$

which is easily derived from $(1)$.

Comment: Your expression for $A(x)$ seems incorrect; it doesn't expand to the correct series.

Answer (score 0):

Let the OGF of odd parts be $o(z)=\frac{z}{1-z^2}$ (i.e. one of each odd size), and of (non-zero) even parts be $e(z)=\frac{z^2}{1-z^2}$ .

The compositions you require consist of a (possibly empty) sequence of pairs of "odd part followed by even part", and then an optional final odd part, so the OGF is
$$c(z)\;=\;
\frac{1}{1-o(z)e(z)}(1+o(z))\;=\;\frac{(1-z^2) (1+z-z^2)}{1 -2 z^2-z^3+z^4}.
$$
For $n\geqslant0$, the series begins $1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 21, 27, 43, 64, 92, 144$.